# Why is it нас миллиарды, not мы миллиарды?

Tags: грамматика

In the following sentence:

> Нас миллиарды на земле.

Source: https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/30984756

Why is this accusative or genitive, not nominative? The sentence is translated into English "We are billions on the Earth.".

---

I found [another example](https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/45536032):

> Их сотни миллионов.

Comment: There are too many of us, he thought. There are billions of us and that's too many.(Bradbury) we use this variant.

Answer (score 8):

Because a closer translation would be "There are billions of us on Earth". This "of us" translates to "нас". Same with "Их миллиарды..." - "Billions of them..."

Comment: And if there is no translation? Then what is the mstter?

Comment: "их миллиарды" might also mean "their billions" depending on context.